# Comparing Java Boolean class

Tags: java, boolean

I was stunned to learn that comparing two Boolean Objects with == can get the wrong answer.

Look at the test code below.  Test a and Test c give consistent answers.

Test b fails.  It seems that new Boolean(true) can create a separate object with the same value, instead of returning a reference to Boolean.TRUE;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Boolean a = Boolean.TRUE; 
    Boolean b = new Boolean(true); 
    Boolean c = null; 
    boolean x = true;
    boolean y = false;

    System.out.println("Test a");
    System.out.println(( a == Boolean.TRUE ) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    System.out.println(( Boolean.TRUE.equals(a)) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    System.out.println("Test b");
    System.out.println(( b == Boolean.TRUE ) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    System.out.println(( Boolean.TRUE.equals(b)) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    System.out.println("Test c");
    System.out.println(( c == Boolean.TRUE ) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    System.out.println(( Boolean.TRUE.equals(c)) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");

    /*  OUTPUT is
    Test a
    TRUE
    TRUE
    Test b
    FALSE
    TRUE
    Test c
    FALSE
    FALSE        
    */
}
```

Comment: What's the question?  That's the way Java works, like it or not.

Comment: That's true...so what is the question?

Comment: Perhaps explore why you think calling a constructor is going to return to you something. Or rather, if you were to write the parameterized constructor for `Boolean`, how do you think you would write it to return `Boolean.TRUE`?

Comment: The moral of the story, Don't create your own instance of TRUE and FALSE, how many objects to represent true and false do you need?  Also `==` is not the same as `equals()`

Comment: Given any reasonable knowledge of Java, would you be surprised by `new Boolean(true) != new Boolean(true)`?

Comment: Anthony ... please excuse late response, but yes, I think the optimization you describe does not violate any Java rules, and it is efficient, just like CharUtils.toCharacterObject() that maintains a much larger set of precreated objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `Boolean` is a reference type and `==` tests if they are the same object in memory then you get false because you allocated `b` with `new`.